# WebBrowser control not working

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 app with C#.

I'm trying to do a login with Facebook Login Page.

Here is my cs source:

```
namespace FacebookLogin
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private const string appId = "xxx";
        private const string apiKey = "xxx"; //insert your apps key here... see developers.facebook.com/setup/
        private readonly string[] extendedPermissions = new[] { "user_about_me" };
        private bool loggedIn = false;
        private FacebookClient fbClient;
        PhoneApplicationService appService = PhoneApplicationService.Current;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fbClient = new FacebookClient();
            FacebookLoginBrowser.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(FacebookLoginBrowser_Loaded);
            //FacebookLoginBrowser.Navigated +=new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(FacebookLoginBrowser_Navigated);
        }

        private void FacebookLoginBrowser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!loggedIn)
            {
                LoginToFacebook();
            }
        }

        private void FacebookLoginBrowser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
            if (FacebookOAuthResult.TryParse(e.Uri, out oauthResult))
            {
                if (oauthResult.IsSuccess)
                {
                    fbClient = new FacebookClient(oauthResult.AccessToken);
                    loggedIn = true;
                    loginSucceeded();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(oauthResult.ErrorDescription);
                }
            }
        }

        private void LoginToFacebook()
        {
            TitlePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            FacebookLoginBrowser.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            InfoPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            var loginParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                      {
                                          { "response_type", "token" }
                                          // { "display", "touch" } // by default for wp7 builds only (in Facebook.dll), display is set to touch.
                                      };

            var navigateUrl = FacebookOAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(appId, null, extendedPermissions, loginParameters);

            FacebookLoginBrowser.Navigate(navigateUrl);
        }

        // At this point we have an access token so we can get information from facebook
        private void loginSucceeded()
        {
            TitlePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            FacebookLoginBrowser.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            InfoPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            fbClient.GetCompleted +=
                (o, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Error == null)
                    {
                        var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MyData.ItemsSource = result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
                    }
                };
            fbClient.GetAsync("/me");
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs args)
        {
            appService.State["fbClient"] = fbClient;
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(args);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my XAML code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="FacebookLogin.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MI APLICACIÓN" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="nombre de la página" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="FacebookLoginBrowser" Height="607" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" />
            <Grid x:Name="InfoPanel" Grid.Row="1">
                <ListBox x:Name="MyData" Height="657" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="500">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Botón 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Botón 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Elemento de menú 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Elemento de menú 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Where is the error? `FacebookLoginBrowser_Navigated` isn't never reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the answer (and I knew it before even looking at your code, but I did doublecheck). The WP7 Browser control defaults to having JavaScript disabled (why they did that is beyond me).  SO, you need to set the "IsScriptEnabled" property of the web browser control to True (you can do this in code or in XAML), and then I bet everything will work.

Comment: As easy as that. One day and a half looking for the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @OffBySome, I thought it was polite to add a comment mentioning what you edited... All I can see is that you removed 87 characters...

Answer (score 0):

You have your FacebookLoginBrowser_Navigated event handler commented out. That is the correct one to use. Not a RoutedEventHandler just an EventHandler.

Also it might not be a bad idea just to set the eventhandler in design view on the browser control if it's not absolutely necessary to dynamically create the event.

Comment: Yes, I've done that but I get the same problem. When I click on Login button, it does nothing (and FacebookLoginBrowser_Navigated isn't reached).